# How close am I to the Guru badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, guru-badge

A few weeks ago, I answered the questions

1. [How to sum up elements of a C++ vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221812/) ([my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221812/sum-of-elements-in-a-stdvector/3221813#3221813))
2. [Is there a better way to initialize an allocated array in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246528/) ([my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246528/is-there-a-better-way-to-initialize-an-allocated-array-in-c/3246543#3246543))

How far am I from getting the Guru badge for the above two questions? Will I get Guru if the count of upvotes is +41 or +40 (including all the upvotes and downvotes)?

Can anyone get a Guru badge for an answer marked as community wiki?

Comment: You are 5 and 8 votes respectively getting the badge (as of the time of writing).

Comment: Someone downvoted both the linked answers as well as this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Guru**](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/18/guru) is awarded if you  have a total score (ups minus downs) of 40 or more (so 5 and 8 more net upvotes for you currently).

[**It can be awarded to community wiki.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441198/has-anyone-learned-how-to-program-in-21-days/441224#441224)

Comment: The link "It can be awarded to community wiki." is invalid.